# Data Frames Coming Out as Tibbles, Rather Than Pages

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

I'm brand new to R and I've run into an odd issue. I am using a Macbook Pro and my R Studio is up to date. When I run code that produces a data frame, it comes out not as a data frame but as a tibble. My classmates all get these pretty data frames that they can scroll to see more, but mine just gives me the image below.

[image: my code on the built-in flights data set]

Is there something in the settings that I need to change? Or something I need to be putting in my code?

Thanks in advance!

**Update:** the issue was due to a [bug](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2748) in an outdated version of RStudio where data frames were not being printed in a paged format. A simple update fixed the issue. Thanks to @camille for the assistance!

Comment: what did you do upstream of this? Where did `flights` come from? It was most likely a tibble *before* you ran this code ...

Comment: You could add `%>% View()` to see the output in the RStudio data viewer. I think you may be using a more current version of `dplyr`, which prints tibbles. Can probably coerce to standard data frame using something like as.data.frame.

Comment: `nycflights13::flights` gives `# A tibble: 336,776 x 19...`. Sounds like your classmates are using the data view pane, as suggested.

Comment: @JonSpring the %>% View() works perfectly, but is there a way to see this without opening a new tab?

Comment: And @neilfws the data frame is showing up dynamically in their code when they run a chunk. Even my professor is confused about why mine isn't doing the same.

Comment: if your professor is confused it's fairly likely that we're not going to be able to debug this remotely ... sorry ...

Comment: this may represent the difference between a "notebook" format (which I hate) and a regular "R code/script" format; check the lower right corner of your script window?

Comment: probably the opposite of this question: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000262407-Stop-displaying-results-in-Rmd-Source-pane-

Comment: I think what you're looking for is paged tables. There was a bug several months ago where versions of R and RStudio combined to not print data frames in a paged format. The issue is [closed](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2748) on Github, so you might try updating R, RStudio, and Rmarkdown

Comment: @camille that's exactly what I was looking for; a simple update fixed the issue. Thanks!